# getting records by id and querying there relation with 'wherebetween' using Laravel and eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

i'm trying to get all measurements from a certain recorder between a certain timespan.
If i remove the "->wherebetween()" part of the query and view the results then I get all the sensors of that recorder and all related measurements of that sensor.
But I'm not able to execute a wherebetween on the relation.

#### query in the controller

```
public function getChart(Request $request) {
    $sensorCollection = Sensor::where('recorder_id', $request->recorder_id)
        ->with('getMeasurementsRelation')
        ->wherebetween('getMeasurementsRelation', function ($query) use ($request) {
            return $query->wherebetween('timestamp',[$request->start_chart, $request->end_chart]);})
            ->get();
}
```

#### Relationship in Sensor model

```
public function getMeasurementsRelation() {
        return $this->hasmany('App\Models\measurement', 'sensor_id', 'id');}
```

Comment: can you post whats the value format of start_chart and end_chart.also is timestamp is of type timestamp

Comment: @JohnLobo The start_chart and end_chart values are provided trough a <input type="date"> field and are formatted as "YYYY-mm-dd" example = "2021-05-10". The column 'timestamp' is of the type 'timestamp'.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use callback in with method like below.Since you have not mentioned start and end chart value format .So i assume its Y-m-d format .if not let me know in comment i can modify my answer according to your need

```
$sensorCollection = Sensor::where('recorder_id', $request->recorder_id)
        ->with(['getMeasurementsRelation'=>function($query)use($request){
            $startChart=\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$request->start_chart)->startOfDay();

            $endChart=\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$request->end_chart)->endOfDay();

            $query->wherebetween('timestamp',[$startChart, $endChart]);
        }])

        ->get();
```

Comment: It worked, thanks!!! 
 I've added "->startOfDay ()" and "->endOfDay ()" to format the time to fixed point. Without this extra formatting I would get different starting en ending points based upon the time(H:m:s) that you searched.

Comment: @vennot_be.okay glad that you solved your issue